# Speed Up Sgen.exe?

Tags: c#, serialization, sgen

I am currently developing a code generation tool that takes an XML Schema and generates C# classes, compiles the C# classes and SGENs them with the sgen.exe to create the serializeable .dll. The problem is that generating the serializable dll from the sgen.exe takes way too long. It could be because my project contains about 1400 serializeable classes.

The sgen.exe completes successfully and generates a valid .dll but it takes about 25 to 30 minutes. This makes testing this project a nightmare. Is there anyway to speed this up? I can see the the sgen.exe is only using 1 core of my processor but I assume that is because sgen.exe cannot be multithreaded. Any ideas how I can speed this up?

Comment: That sounds pretty excessive, hard to guess what should be expected with that many classes though.  Look for environmental causes.  I'd first make an exclusion in anti-malware, look at network traffic with SysInternals' TcpView next.